# Ошибка при загрузке медиа на хостинге на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Выдает ошибку "Не могу создать директорию `wp-content/uploads/`", права доступа везде полные стоят, в инете копал, еще советуют изменить путь на абсолютный (типа когда на хостинг переносишь, так надо) но не могу понять, где изменить конкретно, в настройках нет такого пункта, а в коде не могу понять, где именно и что менять.

Comment: Скорее всего, неправильно перенесли на хостинг: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: я его прям на хостинге создавал, не переносил

Answer (score 1):

поменял права на запись для Группа пулов приложений (IWPG_u0289033) и все заработало

Answer (score 0):

> но не могу понять, где изменить конкретно, в настройках нет такого пункта, а в коде не могу понять, где именно и что менять.

Менять нужно владельца процесса php. Он не имеет прав доступа в каталог, созданный другим владельцем (ftp, юзером, апачем и тп).

Возможно более простым решением будет сменить обработчик php на сервере. В некоторых панелях это делается довольно просто.

Иначе - создать каталог вручную и дать ему рекурсивно права 777. Но это не очень хороший вариант.